# Thread Termination Condition

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm writing a producer-consumer thread program in C. Everything in my program is working perfectly with one major exception. When I have more than one consumer thread, which is pretty much always, only the first consumer thread will actually terminate. I've tried absolutely everything that I can think of, but the problem persists. Here's my code, with the guts of it stripped out, so that you can see just the part that is relevant.

I can see from my output that both of the termination condition variables become zero, which is of course why the first consumer thread terminates. But why don't the other consumer threads also terminate?

Thank you!

```
sem_t full, empty, mutex;
int threads;
int to_consume;
FILE* inputfp[5];
FILE* outputfp = NULL;
char in[BUF];

void* p(void* inpFile) {

    while (fscanf(inpFile, FMTSTRING, in) > 0) {
        sem_wait(&empty);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        // production code here
        to_consume++;
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
     }

    fclose (inpFile);

    sem_wait(&mutex);
    threads--;
    sem_post(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}

void* c() {

    int continuing = 1;

    while (continuing) {

        sem_wait(&full);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        //consumption code here
        to_consume--;
        fprintf("%d %d\n", threads, to_consume); //these both go to zero by the end

        if ( (threads <= 0) && (to_consume <= 0) ) {
            continuing = 0;
        }

        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int i;
    int con_threads;
    con_threads = 3;
    to_consume = 0;

    pthread_t *pr_thread[argc-2];
    pthread_t *con_thread[2];

    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, 50);
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    for (i = 0; i < (argc-2); i++) {
        pr_thread[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)); 
        inputfp[i] = fopen(argv[i+1], "r");
        int rc = pthread_create (pr_thread[i], NULL, p, inputfp[i]);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        threads++;
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }

    outputfp = fopen(argv[(argc-1)], "wb");

    for (i = 0; i con_threads 3; i++) {
        con_thread[i] = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
        int rc = pthread_create (con_thread[i], NULL, c, NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (argc - 2); i++) {
        pthread_join(*pr_thread[i], 0);
        free(pr_thread[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i con_threads 3; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "About to close consumer thread %d.\n", i);
        pthread_join(*res_thread[i], 0);
        fprintf(stderr, "Consumer thread %d closed successfully.\n", i);
        free(res_thread[i]);
    }

    printf ("About to close the output file.\n");
    /* Close the output file */
    fclose (outputfp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You might consider using more meaningful function names, such as `producer()` instead of `p()` and `consumer()` instead of `c()`.

Comment: Most semaphore implementations require a mutex that must be explicitly locked before the critical section.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i con_threads 3; i++)` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't post `full` again when the first consumer detects that there are no threads left, so the second consumer is waiting on `full` but the signal will never arrive.  You may need a count of the consumers, though for a first pass (proof of concept), you can leave `full` with a post that is never read.

Comment: Actually, this answer isn't quite right. What I think that I have is a classic case of deadlock. The consumer thread is waiting for sem_post(&full) to be called so that it has something to work with. However, the only threads that can call that are the producer threads, who have all finished up. I need to figure out what to do here, but at least I know what the issue is. Thanks for pointing out that the consumer was waiting for the post. Now I know what to think about!

Comment: I was thinking/assuming that in the `consumer()`, at the paragraph `if ((threads <= 0) && (to_consume <= 0)) { continuing = 0; }` you would add: `if ((threads <= 0) && (to_consume <= 0)) { continuing = 0; sem_post(&full); }`.  You'll only have the consumer post to `full` when there are no producers left to post to `full`, so it should be safe.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured it out. I created a test, along the lines of what you are suggesting, so that the first instance where all of the producer threads had exited and all of the produced items had been processed, that consumer thread would sem_post(full) for exactly the number of consumer threads (minus one). That would allow the other consumer threads to get past the sem_wait(full). Then I had a return statement immediately following so that those other threads would just terminate. Thanks for following up. I appreciate it.